# Firebase value in angular2 when displayed in a list

Tags: typescript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

**This is the load, add and mark ToDo as Finished:**

```
    todos: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

    ngOnInit(){
        this.todos = this._af.database.list('todos')
    }

    addTodo(newTodo: string){
        this.todos.push({
            todo: newTodo
        } )
    }

    finishedTodo(key: string, finished: boolean, isFinished: boolean){

        var snapshotFinished = this._af.database.object('todos/'+ key,{ preserveSnapshot: true})

        snapshotFinished.subscribe(snapshot => {          
            isFinished = snapshot.val().finished;  
        });

        if (isFinished == false || isFinished == null){
            this.todos.update(key,{finished: true});
            isFinished = true;
            console.log(isFinished);
        }    
        else{
            this.todos.update(key,{finished: false});
            isFinished = false;
            console.log(isFinished);
        }
    }
```

**And this is the html:**

```
<div *ngFor="let todo of todos | async">

    <span> {{todo.todo}} </span>

    <button (click)="finishedTodo(todo.$key)">Finished</button>
</div>
```

Clicking the Finished button works for toggling the `finished` value into true or false inside Firebase. But i don't know how to use that back in the Angular2 list.

So my question is : when displaying the list of todos, how can i **check the `finished` value from inside Firebase for each item in the list**?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a checkbox to your template HTML and reference `todo.finished` for your `finished` boolean value.

```
<div *ngFor="let todo of todos | async">
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="{{ todo.finished }}">
  <span>{{ todo.todo }}</span>
  <button (click)="finishedTodo(todo.$key)">Finished</button>
</div>
```